# javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: In &lt;parseDate&gt;, value attribute can not be parsed

Tags: jsp, date, jstl

I have a `Calendar` object that I'm trying to pass to the JSP and format with JSTL into my own custom format:

`<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>`

```
<c:forEach items="${employees}" var="employee" varStatus="loop">
                <fmt:parseDate value="${employee.startDate}" var="parsedStartDate" pattern="HH:mm dd/MM/yyyy z" />
                <fmt:parseDate value="${employee.endDate}" var="parsedEndDate" pattern="HH:mm dd/MM/yyyy z" />
                var contentString = '<div id="content">' +
                        '<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading" style="font-size: 11px;"><p style="color: green">${parsedStartDate}</p> to <p style="color: orange">${parsedEndDate}</p></h1>' +
                        '<div id="bodyContent">' +
                        '<p style="font-size: 14px;">${employee.details}</p>' +
                        '</div>' +
                        '</div>';
</c:forEach>
```

The `employee` object is a standard `Calendar.getInstance();` object.

edit, full exception:

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=1417392000000,areFieldsSet=true,areAllFieldsSet=true,lenient=true,zone=sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="Europe/London",offset=0,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,transitions=242,lastRule=java.util.SimpleTimeZone[id=Europe/London,offset=0,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,startYear=0,startMode=2,startMonth=2,startDay=-1,startDayOfWeek=1,startTime=3600000,startTimeMode=2,endMode=2,endMonth=9,endDay=-1,endDayOfWeek=1,endTime=3600000,endTimeMode=2]],firstDayOfWeek=2,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=4,ERA=1,YEAR=2014,MONTH=11,WEEK_OF_YEAR=49,WEEK_OF_MONTH=1,DAY_OF_MONTH=1,DAY_OF_YEAR=335,DAY_OF_WEEK=2,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=1,AM_PM=0,HOUR=0,HOUR_OF_DAY=0,MINUTE=0,SECOND=0,MILLISECOND=0,ZONE_OFFSET=0,DST_OFFSET=0]"
    at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:366)
    at org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.fmt.ParseDateSupport.doEndTag(ParseDateSupport.java:187)
    at org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspx_meth_fmt_005fparseDate_005f0(index_jsp.java:459)
    at org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fforEach_005f0(index_jsp.java:405)
    at org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:142)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:388)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:436)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:374)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:302)
    at com.example.controller.EmployeeController.doGet(EmployeeController.java:48)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:620)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

`at com.example.controller.EmployeeController.doGet(EmployeeController.java:48)` is: `request.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp").forward(request, response);`

Comment: what is the complete error?

Comment: updated question with it

Comment: how is startDate defined in employee class? looks like it is a Calendar instance instead of Date object

Comment: `private Calendar startDate;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

parseDate is used to parse string input and convert to Date object. You should not use parseDate. Instead use formatDate

```
<c:forEach items="${employees}" var="employee" varStatus="loop">
   var contentString = '<div id="content">' +
     '<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading" style="font-size: 11px;"><p style="color: green">
    <fmt:formatDate type="time" value="${employee.startDate.time}" pattern="HH:mm dd/MM/yyyy z"/></p> to <p style="color: orange">
    <fmt:formatDate type="time" value="${employee.endDate.time}" pattern="HH:mm dd/MM/yyyy z" /></p></h1>' +
    '<div id="bodyContent">' +
    '<p style="font-size: 14px;">${employee.details}</p>' +
    '</div>' +
    '</div>';
</c:forEach>
```