# Compare calendar dates in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, calendar, jstl

I have to check if the date I am getting has passed 24 hours or not, I have tried many things but failed.

My date from the database looks like this:

> 2017-06-14 13:18:01.0000000

It's a [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) object. And I have to check if this date has passed 24 hours in `if` statement.

How to add hours in time so I can add 24 hours and compare it with the current time?

Comment: Did you see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27603116/javax-servlet-servletexception-javax-servlet-jsp-jspexception-in-ltparsedate?

Answer (score 2):

It is better to check dates in backend.

```
public boolean isDateValid() {
...
}
```

and in JSTL

```
<c:if test="${yourModel.dateValid}">
...
</c:if>
```